# Eigenvalue Bound of Block Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following eigenvalue problem for block matrices A and B

\begin{equation}
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} \end{array} \right]v = \lambda 
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
B_{11} & B_{12} & 0 \\
B_{21} & B_{22} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & B_{33} \end{array} \right]v
\end{equation}
where matrix $B$ is symmetric and positive definite and matrix $A$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite. All blocks are square and of the same size.

I) If $B_{12}=B_{21}=0$, Can I say anything about $\max(\lambda)$?

II) How does setting $B_{12}$ and $B_{21}$ to zero shift $\max(\lambda)$?

Comment: This is not eigenvalues. What are you even trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $$\begin{bmatrix}
  A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} 
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  v_1 \\
  v_2 \\
  v_3
 \end{bmatrix}=\lambda B_{11}v_1$$  for case (I), then the first entry works.